# Is this a tangent bundle and what is the meaning of this exercise

Tags: matrices, differential-geometry, lie-groups, vector-bundles

I intend to solve the following exercise but I would like to have some help with understanding the ''big picture'':

> Exercise. Describe a natural 1 to 1 correspondence between elements of
>   $SO(3)$ and elements of $$T^1S^2=\{(p,v)\in \mathbb R^3 \times \mathbb
>  R^3 | |p|=|v|=1 \text{ and } p \bot v \}$$
>
> which can be thought of as the collection of all unit-length vectors
>   $v$ tangent to all points $p$ of $S^2$.

At this point $SO(3)$ has been defined to be the set of all positions of a globe on a fixed stand. Since this seemed to be too sloppy to use I did some googling and found that $SO(3)$ is the set of all orthogonal matrices with determinant equal to $1$. So now my intention is to find a bijection from this set of matrices into $T^1S^2$.

But before I embark on this task I would like to understand what this exercise is really about. What exactly is $T^1S^2$? At first I thought it was the tangent bundle of $S^2$ but the tangent bundle has a slightly different definition in that its elements are equivalence classes whereas here we are talking about points in $\mathbb R^6$. Also, the notation is different: the tangent bundle would be denoted $TS^2$ but the notation used here is $T^1S^2$.

I am looking for some information about the meaning of this bijection in the exercise. I have no (very little) prior knowledge of differential geometry. Thank you.

Comment: This is the unit tangent bundle. It's like the tangent bundle, but it only contains unit vectors. Visualize it in terms of little circles surrounding each point of the $2$-sphere. Now, $\text{SO}(3)$ acts on the $2$-sphere by rotation. I claim that this action extends to an action on the unit tangent bundle which is free and transitive. See if you can explicitly visualize this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the description given, $T^1 S^2 \subset TS^2$ denotes the unit tangent bundle inside $TS^2$: each fiber $(T^1 S^2)_p$ is the unit sphere in $(TS^2)_p$. (The metric used is the one corresponding to the embedding $TS^2\subset \theta^3$, where $\theta\to S^2$ denotes the trivial bundle, coming from the usual embedding $S^2\subset \mathbb{R}^3$.)

For the bijection, note that each point $(p, v)\in T^1 S^2$ has $p$ and $v$ orthonormal. The matrix with columns $p, v, (p\times v)$ then lies in $SO(3)$.

Comment: Thank you. Reading Qiachu's comment above it seems that the unit tangent bundle is a space and $SO(3)$ is a group acting on it. But if that is so could you tell me please why it makes sense that this tangent bundle is in bijection with rotations? I mean, intuitively, I don't quite see why a point in a tangent space should be equivalent to a rotation. There seems to be too much information in the tangent space point. Like, if we were just considering points on $S^2$ then it would seem intuitive that such a point corresponds to the rotation moving the north pole to the point.

Comment: Is it better if I create a new question for this?

Comment: Think of $TS^2$ and $T^1S^2$ as being embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ in the usual way, corresponding to the embedding $S^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$. The group $SO(3)$ acts on $\mathbb{R}^3$ by rotations, and that action extends to one on $TS^2$ and $T^1 S^2$. In short: $SO(3)$ acts on the base space $S^2$. This action extends to one on the tangent bundle; this can be seen through the embedding above, or by the fact that the derivative $Dg:T\mathbb{R}^3 \to T\mathbb{R}^3$ of $g\in SO(3) : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is just $g$ itself.

Comment: It's not hard to show that that action is free and transitive, and so gives the required bijection. Geometrically, it's pretty much the same as the action of $SO(3)$ on $S^2$: the group $SO(3)$ acts transitively on $S^2$, and the stabilizer of a point $p\in S^2$ is $SO(2)$, acting by rotation around the line through the origin and $p$. But now we also have to take into account the action of $SO(3)$ on the tangent space at $p$ (namely, rotation by an element of $SO(2)$), which kills the stabilizer. The construction is a bit awkward to describe, but think of $SO(3)$ acting on the north pole.